# Bootstrap Radio button not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I am trying to use this bootstrap radio button [Bootstrap Snippet](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/e38pa). But it gives an error on form submit. Below is the console error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: checkNullProf is not defined
```

Anyone who have used this snippet and knows how to use. I have tried to search about it, but I didn't get any help for it.

Comment: Well then remove that part from the code ...?

Answer (score 1):

This method is `undefined`. So define it, as you would define a normal function. Make it do whatever you want it to do.

```
checkNullProf() {
//Anything you want... :) 
}
```

Maybe you want to display a popup window when the radio button is pressed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have the method checkNullProf() defined. You must create the method.

Edited:

```
<script>
function checkNullProf(){
alert("the method works!")
}
</script>
```

Comment: That I understand, but what to write on that method.